# ¿Como crear en JS una variable equivalente a una variable static en PHP?

Tags: variables, if, variables-globales

```
function cambiarPropiedades(elemento){
        if(typeof control === "undefined"){
            control = true; //No puedo usar el operador var
        }
        if(control == true){
            //Código a ejecutar
            control = false;
        } else {
            //Otro código a ejecutar
            control = true;
        }
    }
```

No puedo usar el operador `var` al definir `control` porque el código no funciona pues crea una variable de ámbito local, y por lo tanto, cada vez que se ejecuta y muere la función, muere con ella la variable y su valor, así que siempre entraría en el primer `if` y el resultado siempre sería el mismo.
Recuerdo que cuando di algunas pinceladas básicas en PHP me explicaron y toqueteé un poco el operador `static`, que permitía definir una variable que no se destruye cuando la función muere.

Hay alguna forma de hacer algo equivalente? En el ejemplo podéis ver que he optado por declarar la variable `control` como una variable global pero me gustaría que no sea así, para evitar problemas y por pura curiosidad. Tampoco me convence llamarla _control para indicar su ambito local y diferenciarla. ¿Es posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta utilizando [cache de funciones o memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Como todo en javascript en objecto, puedes agregarle en ejecución una propiedad a las funciones y utilizarlas como *cache*:

```js
function cambiarPropiedades(elemento){
 if(cambiarPropiedades.control == true){
  //Código a ejecutar
  cambiarPropiedades.control = false;
    console.log("control=true");
 } else {
  //Otro código a ejecutar
  cambiarPropiedades.control = true;
    console.log("control=false");
 }
}

cambiarPropiedades.control = true;
cambiarPropiedades({});

cambiarPropiedades.control = false;
cambiarPropiedades({});
```

Así entonces tiene una variable que no se elimina la referencia cuando se termine la ejecución de la función y es no global.